# glossaries : accent commands in 'see' references

Tags: glossaries, accents

Using the `glossaries` package, referencing another entry in `\newglossaryentry` with the `see=label` key, the following problem occurs if the `name=...` key of the referenced label has accent commands:

[image]

```
\newglossaryentry{right-view}
{name={Right View},
description={The first factor of the Noble Eightfold Path},
see=samma-ditthi}

\newglossaryentry{samma-ditthi}
{name={samm\=a-di\d{t}\d{t}hi},
description={Right View, the first of the eight factors of the Noble Eightfold Path, the path leading to \textit{nibb\=ana}. In the highest sense to have Right View means to understand the Four Noble Truths}}

\gls{right-view}, \gls{samma-ditthi}
```

**How to fix this?**

Comment: I removed the {cross-referencing} tag from this question (and from two others). The tag is more appropriate for questions about `\label` and `\ref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sanitize` option. See p. 26--27 of the glossaries [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries.pdf) for details (and keep an eye out for possible adverse effects).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sanitize=none]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{right-view}
{name={Right View},
description={The first factor of the Noble Eightfold Path},
see=samma-ditthi}

\newglossaryentry{samma-ditthi}
{name={samm\=a-di\d{t}\d{t}hi},
description={Right View, the first of the eight factors of the Noble Eightfold Path, the path leading to \textit{nibb\=ana}. In the highest sense to have Right View means to understand the Four Noble Truths}}

\begin{document}

\gls{right-view}, \gls{samma-ditthi}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Marvellous! Goodness gracious I've been poring over the wrong parts of the documentation.